# compilation terminated fatal error: abc.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, pthreads, jnienv

The project is all about handshaking Cpp with java For that i am using JNI, I made all the necesaary configuration make Cpp project generate header in src folder of Cpp project  create ABC.h file and abc.Cpp file. when i bulid the abc.cpp file it shows error compilation failed due to p.thread no such directory found, if i remove this P.thread header file it shows ABC.h not found while ABC.h file is in same folder and we include on our Cpp file 
please help me out how to fix this problem ,i am newbie in JNI
below attached PNG file show you the detail

```
ERROR ON ECLIPSE CONSOLE//////////////////////////////////////////

00:31:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project SyntacJNI ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_21\\include\\win32" "-IC:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_21\\include" -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\abc
.o" "..\\src\\abc.cpp" 
..\src\abc.cpp:10:21: fatal error:abc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

00:31:21 Build Finished (took 189ms)

///////////////////////////abc.cpp//////////////CODE Snippet////////////////////////

    #include <fstream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <SyntacInterface.h>
    #include <org_syntec_ivb_jni_DeviceCommunicationController.h>

    using namespace std;

    // An unsigned char can store 1 Bytes (8bits) of data (0-255)
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;
    // Global Var

    bool gLive_View = true;
    // Get the size of a file

    #include <stdlib.h>
    ULONG RcvdBytes;
    volatile bool keepRunning = false;
    volatile bool modeFlag = true;
    static HANDLE hThread = NULL;
    int compstr = 0xFF000F00;
    long int count = 0;
    static void run();
    static void end();
    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam);
    static ULONG BuffSizeLive = 81408;
    //CRITICAL_SECTION critical;
    int got = 0;

    static void run() {
        DWORD dummy;
        hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, &dummy);
    }
    static void end() {
        keepRunning = false;
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    bool fexists(const char *filename) {
        ifstream ifile(filename);
        return ifile.good();
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam) {
        while (keepRunning) {

            BuffSizeLive = 327680;

            UCHAR* Buff = (UCHAR*) malloc(sizeof(UCHAR) * BuffSizeLive);

            ULONG RcvdBytes;
            RcvdBytes = abc_GetCapture(Buff, BuffSizeLive);
            if (RcvdBytes == 327680 || RcvdBytes == 81408) {

                Syntac_WriteToBinaryFile(Buff,
                        "C:/listenDir/Capture_Mod1.BIN", RcvdBytes);
            }
            free(Buff);
            cout << "got the frame stream " << got;
        }
        return 0;
    }][1]
```

Comment: Your description does not match with the snippet you have provided. What's the file name - ABC.h or abc.h? Where have you included it? The error message that you have pasted - was it when pthread include was removed or not removed? In the build command, shouldn't it be `-o "..\\src\\abc.o"` (note the additional `..`).

Comment: @rockoder ABC.H is header file generated in JNI from Java Class and Abc.cpp is cPP file in Which i include P.thread header file compilation terminated error shows

Comment: when i remove the p.thread from Cpp file it show Same error On ABC.h header which is generated by java Class in CPP project within SRC FOLDER in same Folder Also created Cpp file Include the ABC.h file then also it show Error of Compilation terminated

Comment: You are getting error at line 10. Wild guess - make sure you include the user header files using "" instead of <>.